# Flutter: Get the filename of a File

Tags: filenames, flutter

I thought this would be pretty straight-forward, but can't seem to get this. I have a `File file` and it has a path `file.path` which spits out something like `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my_app/files/Pictures/ca04f332.png` but I can't seem to find anything to get just `ca04f332.png`.

Comment: Every answer I could find anywhere, is some variation of parsing the full path. This is brutally inefficient, and it matters a lot if you are going to walk a large and deep tree of files, for example to find a filename that matches a certain regex. Even Python would be faster at this. Really? We must parse the whole path?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You can use the [`basename`](https://pub.dev/documentation/path/latest/path/basename.html) function from the dart [path library](https://pub.dev/documentation/path/latest/path/path-library.html):

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';

File file = new File("/dir1/dir2/file.ext");
String basename = basename(file.path);
# file.ext
```

Comment: Don't forgot to import path.dart     =>       

import 'package:path/path.dart';

Comment: under some reasons am getting a file name without extension, so how can i get the file extension. /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my_app/files/Pictures/ca04f332

Comment: or can use the basename function without extension:
 `String basename = basenameWithoutExtension(file.path);`

Comment: @b.john get the path `String path = file.path;` and file name with extension `fileName = path.split('/').last;`

Comment: Just a note to my issue, If you use **BLoC** and using `part` and `part of` for file organizer, adding `import 'package:path/path.dart';` will gave error to the `context.read<YourCubit>().yourMethod();` code line

Comment: recommended because path is different in cross platform

Answer (score 79):

```
File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my_app/files/Pictures/ca04f332.png"); 
String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;

print(fileName);
```

output = ca04f332.png

Comment: simple and effective and also supports http path which is another +1

Comment: You should replace '/' with `Platform.pathSeparator`

Answer (score 12):

Since Dart Version `2.6` has been announced and it's available for flutter version `1.12` and higher, You can use `extension` methods. It will provide a more readable and global solution to this problem.

`file_extensions.dart` :

```
import 'dart:io';

extension FileExtention on FileSystemEntity{
  String get name {
    return this?.path?.split(Platform.pathSeparator)?.last;
  }
}
```

and `name` getter is added to all the file objects. You can simply just call `name` on any file.

```
main() {
  File file = new File("/dev/dart/work/hello/app.dart");
  print(file.name);
}
```

Read the [document](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) for more information.

**Note:**
Since `extension` is a new feature, it's not fully integrated into IDEs yet and it may not be recognized automatically. You have to import your `extension` manually wherever you need that. Just make sure the extension file is imported:

```
import 'package:<your_extention_path>/file_extentions.dart';
```

Comment: For the sake of total completeness, should the this?.path?.split(...) call be modified to use pathSeparator in cases of running on Windows? Or does Dart / Flutter always work with a "/" character at the language level? (I think Java does that, too).

Comment: @ChrisH Actually by the time that I wrote this answer, I didn't know that `Platform.pathSeparator` is exist. Yes, It would be a better approach if you use `Platform.pathSeparator` instead of `'/'`

Comment: @ChrisH feel free to suggest an edit on my answer and I will accept it

Comment: if anyone want to do it on `filePath` as a `String` then use this
`extension FileExtention on String {
  String get name {
    return this?.split("/")?.last;
  }
}
`

Answer (score 6):

##### Direct way:

```dart
File file = File('/foo/bar/baz/my_image.jpg');
String fileName = file.path.split(Platform.pathSeparator).last; // my_image.jpg
```

---

##### Using an extension:

**1. Create an extension:**

```dart
extension FileEx on File {
  String get name => path.split(Platform.pathSeparator).last;
}
```

**2. Usage:**

```dart
File file = File('/foo/bar/baz/my_image.jpg');
String fileName = file.name; // my_image.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to get name or any other file handling operations.I recommend to use this plugin : https://pub.dev/packages/file_support

```
main() {
  String filename= FileSupport().getFileNameWithoutExtension(<File Object>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cane use extension method  **No need to use any package**

**Create Method like this**

```
extension FileNameExtension on File {
  String getFileName() {
    String fileName = path.split('/').last;
    return fileName;
  }
}
```

**implement**

```
File file = File("yourpath/example.pdf");
file.getFileName() // result =>  example.pdf
```